# What do < and > mean such as implements Comparable<BigInteger>?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, comparable

In [Java 1.4.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-138567.html), class [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://web.archive.org/web/20111208190928/https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) implements interfaces `Comparable`, `Serializable`.

In [Java 1.5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html), class [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) implements interfaces `Serializable`, `Comparable<BigInteger>`.

This is just an example to help me ask about `<` and `>`.  What I am really wondering about is the `<` and `>` stuff.

My question is threefold:

- what does the `<BigInteger>` part of the `implements` statement mean?
- what is that syntax called?
- and what does it do?

P.S.: It's really hard to google for `<` and `>` and impossible to search SO for `<` and `>` in the first place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Read the [Java Generics Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).  The thing between the angle brackets is a type parameter - Comparable is a generic class, and in this case the angle brackets mean that the class is comparable to other BigIntegers.

For a little more clarification in this case, have a look at the [Javadocs for Comparable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/) in 1.5.  Note that it is declared as `Comparable<T>`, and that the `compareTo` method takes an argument of type `T`.  The T is a type parameter that is "filled in" when the interface is used.  Thus in this case, declaring you implement `Comparable<BigInteger>` implies that you must have a `compareTo(BigInteger o)` method.  Another class might implement `Comparable<String>` meaning that it would have to implement a `compareTo(String o)` method.

Hopefully you can see the benefit from the above snippet.  In 1.4, the signature of `compareTo` could only ever take an `Object` since all kinds of classes implemented Comparable and there was no way to know exactly what was needed.  With generics, however, you can specify that you are comparable with respect to a particular class, and then write a more specific compareTo method that only takes that class as a parameter.

The benefits here are two-fold.  Firstly, you don't need to do an `instanceof` check and a cast in your method's implementation.  Secondly, the compiler can do a lot more type checking at compile time - you can't accidentally pass a String into something that implements `Comparable<BigInteger>`, since the types don't match.  It's much better for the compiler to be able to point this out to you, rather than have this cause a runtime exception as would have generally happened in non-generic code.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure it is Generics

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html

I asked something similar (C#) it has useful info there [What does Method<ClassName> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305651/what-does-methodclassname-mean)