# What does <Something> in ClassName<Something > in java indicate?

Tags: java

I was reading [some](http://Key%3CCar%3E%20rootKey%20=%20new%20Key%3CCar%3E%28Car.class,%20959%29;) tutorial where I came across terms like
`Key<Car> rootKey = new Key<Car>(Car.class, 959);`
What does `<Car>` mean in this code? Why are these "<>" symbols used here? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to the world of generics.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/generics.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do < and > mean such as implements Comparable<BigInteger>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450520/what-do-and-mean-such-as-implements-comparablebiginteger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  in your snippet represents a generic type specifier.  You can instantiate class Key with a type other than Car and its methods will be type-safe for that variable at compile time.

For example, the following statement is type-safe, just as your example is:

```
Key<String> rootKey = new Key<String>(String.class, "someString");
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Java Generic Types: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Car is your "Car-Object class" you are passing in.
2. <> symbols are used for specifying type of Object you want for your Key class